# Python equivalent to JS `Symbol`?

Tags: javascript, python, symbols, uniqueidentifier, nonce

Javascript [symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) provide simple unique identifiers:

```js
> const foo1 = Symbol('foo');
> foo1
Symbol(foo)
> const foo2 = Symbol('foo');
> foo1 === foo2
false
> let m = new Map();
> m.set(foo1, "bar");
> m.set(foo2, "rosco");
> m.get(foo1)
'bar'
> m.get(foo2)
'rosco'
```

This is useful for e.g. having unique return values from functions with special meanings when you can't use `Exception`s.

I know in python you can use `object()` or a [nonce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5590170/what-is-the-standard-method-for-generating-a-nonce-in-python) but neither of those render nice when you print them.

Is there anything like javascript's `Symbol` available in python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Edited:**

This class mimics the javascript counterpart.

Unlike js, Python accepts an object's instance as dictionary key; this code just add a proper representation when printing the symbol.

```
class Symbol:
    def __init__(self, name=''):
        self.name = f"Symbol({name})"
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

# === test ===

foo1 = Symbol('foo')
print(foo1)
foo2 = Symbol('foo')
print(foo1 == foo2)
m = {}
m[foo1] = "bar"
m[foo2] = "rosco"

print(m[foo1])
print(m[foo2])

> Symbol(foo)
> False
> bar
> rosco
```

Comment: When you answer on stackoverflow, you generally need to give an explanation. Please explain what you have tried here. Thanks!